# How can I access dict from JSON dict after making an API call?

Tags: python, python-requests, request

i want to access the values in the dict but i can not do response["establishments"] because there is a strange b symbol in the dict when it was return . How can I get rid of the b symbol so i can access the dict ?

```
b'{"establishments":[{"FHRSID":775937,"ChangesByServerID":0,"LocalAuthorityBusinessID":"13/00068/COMM","BusinessName":"Lexington Catering - Fidessa Restaurant","BusinessType":"Restaurant/Cafe/Canteen","BusinessTypeID":1,"AddressLine1":"Block E First To Seventh Floors Dukes Court Duke Street Woking Surrey","AddressLine2":"","AddressLine3":"","AddressLine4":"","PostCode":"GU21 5BH","Phone":"","RatingValue":"5","RatingKey":"fhrs_5_cy-gb","RatingDate":"2020-01-10T00:00:00","LocalAuthorityCode":"315","LocalAuthorityName":"Woking","LocalAuthorityWebSite":"http://www.woking.gov.uk","LocalAuthorityEmailAddress":"emma.bourne@woking.gov.uk","scores":{"Hygiene":0,"Structural":0,"ConfidenceInManagement":0},"SchemeType":"FHRS","geocode":{"longitude":"-0.554158","latitude":"51.320771"},"RightToReply":"","Distance":null,"NewRatingPending":false,"meta":{"dataSource":null,"extractDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","itemCount":0,"returncode":null,"totalCount":0,"totalPages":0,"pageSize":0,"pageNumber":0},"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/establishments/775937"}]},{"FHRSID":1474143,"ChangesByServerID":0,"LocalAuthorityBusinessID":"22/00013/COMM","BusinessName":"Duke\'s Bar & Deli","BusinessType":"Other catering premises","BusinessTypeID":7841,"AddressLine1":"Dukes Bar And Deli 3 Duke Street Woking Surrey","AddressLine2":"","AddressLine3":"","AddressLine4":"","PostCode":"GU21 5BH","Phone":"","RatingValue":"4","RatingKey":"fhrs_4_cy-gb","RatingDate":"2022-02-24T00:00:00","LocalAuthorityCode":"315","LocalAuthorityName":"Woking","LocalAuthorityWebSite":"http://www.woking.gov.uk","LocalAuthorityEmailAddress":"emma.bourne@woking.gov.uk","scores":{"Hygiene":10,"Structural":0,"ConfidenceInManagement":10},"SchemeType":"FHRS","geocode":{"longitude":null,"latitude":null},"RightToReply":"","Distance":null,"NewRatingPending":false,"meta":{"dataSource":null,"extractDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","itemCount":0,"returncode":null,"totalCount":0,"totalPages":0,"pageSize":0,"pageNumber":0},"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/establishments/1474143"}]}],"meta":{"dataSource":"Lucene","extractDate":"2022-09-03T00:50:19.6362148+01:00","itemCount":2,"returncode":"OK","totalCount":2,"totalPages":1,"pageSize":5000,"pageNumber":1},"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/establishments?address=gu21%205bh"}]}'
```

here is my code

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "DNT": "1",
    # "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "cy-GB",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "x-api-version": "2",
    # 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

def get_web_page_content(post_code):
    print('post_code', post_code)
    BOMS = [
        codecs.BOM,
        codecs.BOM_BE,
        codecs.BOM_LE,
        codecs.BOM_UTF8,
        codecs.BOM_UTF16,
        codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE,
        codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE,
        codecs.BOM_UTF32,
        codecs.BOM_UTF32_BE,
        codecs.BOM_UTF32_LE,
    ]

    url = rf'https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Establishments?address={post_code}'
    time.sleep(5)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.content

    for BOM in BOMS:
        if data.startswith(BOM):
            data = json.loads(data[len(BOM):])
            break
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    response = get_web_page_content('GU21 5BH')
    print('response', response)
```

Comment: The `data` does not start with any of the `BOM`s, because **it is not a string** (this is the first thing that should be learned about a) how the Internet works; b) Python 3.x's **correct** treatment of bytes vs text). You are **not supposed to** decode the JSON yourself - that's one of the most important selling points of the Requests library, and something [clearly shown as an example on the front page of the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), in the first code block, right at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access response in different [formats](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) e.g **bytes, json or raw**. Here in your case you are using the bytes way that's why the result is in byte which prefixed with `b`, if you want to access it as **dict** like syntax i.e `response["establishments"]` then you need to use `response.json()`

**Like,**

```
import requests
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "DNT": "1",
    # "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "cy-GB",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "x-api-version": "2",
    #'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

def get_web_page_content(post_code):
    print('post_code', post_code)

    url = rf'https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Establishments?address={post_code}'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    response = get_web_page_content('GU21 5BH')
    print('response', response)
    print('establishments', response["establishments"])
```

Answer (score 1):

The "strange" `b'...'` symbol means you have got bytes object - that's what `response.content` [returns](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/?highlight=content#binary-response-content). To decode json string use `response.json()`:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Accept-Language": "cy-GB",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "x-api-version": "2",
}


def get_web_page_content(post_code):
    print("post_code", post_code)

    url = rf"https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Establishments?address={post_code}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()  # <-- use .json() here to parse JSON response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    response = get_web_page_content("GU21 5BH")
    print("response", response)
```

Prints:

```
post_code GU21 5BH
response {'establishments': [{'FHRSID': 775937, 'ChangesByServerID': 0, 'LocalAuthorityBusinessID': '13/00068/COMM', 'BusinessName': 'Lexington Catering - Fidessa Restaurant', 'BusinessType': 'Restaurant/Cafe/Canteen', 'BusinessTypeID': 1, 'AddressLine1': 'Block E First To Seventh Floors Dukes Court Duke Street Woking Surrey', 'AddressLine2': '', 'AddressLine3': '', 'AddressLine4': '', 'PostCode': 'GU21 5BH', 'Phone': '', 'RatingValue': '5', 'RatingKey': 'fhrs_5_cy-gb', 'RatingDate': '2020-01-10T00:00:00', 'LocalAuthorityCode': '315', 'LocalAuthorityName': 'Woking', 'LocalAuthorityWebSite': 'http://www.woking.gov.uk', 'LocalAuthorityEmailAddress': 'emma.bourne@woking.gov.uk', 'scores': {'Hygiene': 0, 'Structural': 0, 'ConfidenceInManagement': 0}, 'SchemeType': 'FHRS', 'geocode': {'longitude': '-0.554158', 'latitude': '51.320771'}, 'RightToReply': '', 'Distance': None, 'NewRatingPending': False, 'meta': {'dataSource': None, 'extractDate': '0001-01-01T00:00:00', 'itemCount': 0, 'returncode': None, 'totalCount': 0, 'totalPages': 0, 'pageSize': 0, 'pageNumber': 0}, 'links': [{'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/establishments/775937'}]}, {'FHRSID': 1474143, 'ChangesByServerID': 0, 'LocalAuthorityBusinessID': '22/00013/COMM', 'BusinessName': "Duke's Bar & Deli", 'BusinessType': 'Other catering premises', 'BusinessTypeID': 7841, 'AddressLine1': 'Dukes Bar And Deli 3 Duke Street Woking Surrey', 'AddressLine2': '', 'AddressLine3': '', 'AddressLine4': '', 'PostCode': 'GU21 5BH', 'Phone': '', 'RatingValue': '4', 'RatingKey': 'fhrs_4_cy-gb', 'RatingDate': '2022-02-24T00:00:00', 'LocalAuthorityCode': '315', 'LocalAuthorityName': 'Woking', 'LocalAuthorityWebSite': 'http://www.woking.gov.uk', 'LocalAuthorityEmailAddress': 'emma.bourne@woking.gov.uk', 'scores': {'Hygiene': 10, 'Structural': 0, 'ConfidenceInManagement': 10}, 'SchemeType': 'FHRS', 'geocode': {'longitude': None, 'latitude': None}, 'RightToReply': '', 'Distance': None, 'NewRatingPending': False, 'meta': {'dataSource': None, 'extractDate': '0001-01-01T00:00:00', 'itemCount': 0, 'returncode': None, 'totalCount': 0, 'totalPages': 0, 'pageSize': 0, 'pageNumber': 0}, 'links': [{'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/establishments/1474143'}]}], 'meta': {'dataSource': 'Lucene', 'extractDate': '2022-09-03T00:59:03.9485729+01:00', 'itemCount': 2, 'returncode': 'OK', 'totalCount': 2, 'totalPages': 1, 'pageSize': 5000, 'pageNumber': 1}, 'links': [{'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/establishments?address=gu21%205bh'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the JSON using `response.json`:

```
print("response", response.json)
```

The strange `b` thingy represents that it is a bytes object.